# How to Implement fontSize adjustment dialog box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter. I have taken inspiration from this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikitadev.usconstitution&hl=en and I am implementing the fontsize adjustment dialogbox with flutter. I am really stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make static variable and use the value in your default theme. When font size is increased set the value of that variable to this font size.

````
//Initialize a variable at the top to change
double _textDefaultSize = 16;


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
            fontSize: _textDefaultSize, 
            //Use the text Size in the main theme
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TextColor checking"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Example Text",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: _textDefaultSize),
                //Use the font size in all texts
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState() {
                    _textDefaultSize++; //Change the value of variable here
                  }
                },
                child: Text("Increase Size"),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState() {
                    _textDefaultSize--; //Change the value of variable here
                  }
                },
                child: Text("Increase Size"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```
````